# The name " " does not exist in the namespace WPF XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been scratching over this for a long time now. In my WPF project I keep getting the error saying that "The name .... does not exist in the namespace". This happens in the XAML file and because of this I cannot build my application.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    **xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"**
    Height="576" Width="1024" Closed="Window_Closed">
```

Then in Window.Resources I create my resource:

```
<local:CurrentTimeViewModel x:Key="CurrentTimeViewModel"/>
```

This is where the error comes. I checked the CurrentTimeViewModel file and the namespace is correct and everything seems to be correct.

CurrentViewModel:

```
 public class CurrentTimeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Am I missing anything?

**UPDATE:**

The only C# error I see is "The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid Line 1 Position 1

Comment: Is this in the same project?

Comment: Yes all of this is in the same project.

Comment: @johndoe do you have some other build errors that would stop it from compiling?

Comment: Yes, I have quite a few errors, 12 in total but all seems to be of the same category where it says "The name ... does not exist in the namespace"

Comment: @johndoe There's an error in the C# side somewhere - once you get that fixed, the xaml errors will likely go away...

Comment: Try closing the offending XAML files and rebuild. I have on occasion seen this weird behaviour in VS2012 and 2013. I assumed it was a side-effect of ReSharper, since it began after I installed that.

Comment: I updated the question with the C# error that I get. It is coming from a different project linked to the current project.

Comment: Hmm weird I closed all the XAML documents and rebuild as you suggested and now I am left with 3 errors instead of 12/13. Making progress :)

Comment: Is your project depending on that other project that can't be built? If so, also your current project can't be built, and thus VS may not recognize your namespace, even if it's in the same project. Try getting your project to build without that reference in the xaml and reinsert it afterwards. Worked for me many times

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

in below line Change the key of your localresource

```
<local:CurrentTimeViewModel x:Key="CurrentTimeViewModel"/>
```

to

```
<local:CurrentTimeViewModel x:Key="CurrentTimeViewModelChanged"/>
```

and try. As while loading local resource it might affecting somehow.